# query on a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a help with a  small query.

Table A:- status and the contents of it are below.

```
 status_id      status_descrip 
        1          held 
        2          release 
        3          WIP
```

Table B:- Entry is another  table which has some 30 fields. Out of which 2 fields are referring to Table A-> status table. For simplicity i am skipping other fields and jotting down only the fields related with status.

```
 entry_id        design_status         stress_status
     1                 3                   1
     2                 1                   2
     3                 NULL                2
     4                 3                   3
     5                 NULL                1
     6                 NULL               NULL      
     7                 NULL                2
```

I can't change the structure of Entry to split into 2 tables one as design_status and other as stress_status.

Now i want the entries from entry table replace the status with their descriptions. so the output will be

```
   entry_id        design_status_descrip         stress_status_descrip
      1                   WIP                          held
      2                   held                         release
      3                   NULL                         release
      4                   WIP                          WIP.
      5                   NULL                         held
      6                   NULL                         NULL
      7                   NULL                         release
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:-

Question is edited with Entries.

Thankyou for all your responses!

and the query finally working for me is,

```
SELECT     b.entry_id,     design_status_descrip = d.status_descrip,   
  stress_status_descrip = s.status_descrip FROM     entry AS b   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN status AS d     ON b.design_status = d.status_id   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  status AS s     ON b.stress_status = s.status_id
```

do let me know, if i can improve this query.

Comment: Can you please specify what version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to join against the status table twice. I've used INNER JOIN assuming that the design_status and stress_status columns in your schema have proper constraints. Edited for changed requirements.

```
DECLARE @status TABLE
(
    status_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    status_descrip VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT @status SELECT 1,'held' UNION SELECT 2,'release' UNION SELECT 3,'WIP';

DECLARE @b TABLE
(
    entry_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    design_status INT,
    stress_status INT
);

INSERT @b SELECT 1,3,1
UNION SELECT 2,1,2
UNION SELECT 3,NULL,2
UNION SELECT 4,3,3
UNION SELECT 5,NULL,1
UNION SELECT 6,NULL,NULL
UNION SELECT 7,NULL,2;

SELECT
    b.entry_id,
    design_status_descrip = d.status_descrip,
    stress_status_descrip = s.status_descrip
FROM
    @b AS b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @status AS d
    ON b.design_status = d.status_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @status AS s
    ON b.stress_status = s.status_id;
```

Comment: Yep, please post the complete question next time. :-)

Comment: sorry, next time i will be careful.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    e.entry_id, 
    s1.status_descrip as design_status_descrip, 
    s2.status_descrip as stress_status_descrip 
FROM entry e, status s1, status s2 
WHERE 
    e.design_status = s1.status_id 
    AND e.stress_status = s2.status_id
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: I would recommend against the old-style "table, table, table" style of JOINs - too easily, you forget one of the join conditions in the WHERE clause and you end up with a cartesian product. Instead, use the new ANSI style `INNER JOIN status s1 ON e.design_status = s1.status_id` - this is the standard, this is much cleaner and less error prone....

Answer (score 1):

just join twice to the status table

```
From
      Entry e 
     Inner join status ds
    On e. design_status_id = ds.status_id 
     Inner join status ss
    On e.stress_status_id = ss.status_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of approaches, first is the most efficient.

`SELECT
    e.entry_id
    , MAX(CASE WHEN e.design_status = s.status_id THEN s.status_descrip END) AS design_status_descrip
    , MAX(CASE WHEN e.stress_status = s.status_id THEN s.status_descrip END) AS stress_status_descrip
FROM
    dbo.[Entry] e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.[Status] s 
ON  s.status_id = e.design_status
OR  s.status_id = e.stress_status
GROUP BY
    entry_id`

SELECT
    e.entry_id
    , ds.status_descrip AS design_status_descrip
    , ss.status_descrip AS stress_status_descrip
FROM
    dbo.[Entry] e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.[status] ds
ON  ds.status_id = e.design_status
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.[status] ss
ON  ss.status_id = e.stress_status

Comment: My only concern with the first one is that it becomes tricky to add other columns from Entry because of the grouping.

Comment: True but on the flip side I've seen cases where the repeated join approach is repeated, and repeated, and repeated... I can recall 15 joins to the same table on one query I looked at a while ago. Root cause is bad design but as the OP mentioned (can't change the table structure), that's not something we're always able to fix.

Comment: A lookup table this small (even if there were 100 more entries) is almost certainly always going to be in memory, so you're likely to see a much bigger performance difference in estimated plans vs. actuals, even if you do join to it 15 times. The key in this case would be more about the indexes than how the join happens IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have `NULL`'s in your data, in which case ignore all the answers using `INNER JOIN` as this will effectively filter out any row with a null in either column. Instead use a left join.

```
SELECT
   e.entry_id,
   ds.status_description,
   ss.ststua_description
FROM entry e
LEFT JOIN status ds 
  ON e.design_status = ds.status_id
LEFT JOIN status ss 
  ON e.stress_status = ss.status_id
```

Comment: Jamiec, the OP added the NULLs after a bunch of folks had already spent time submitting answers - the original question implied no NULLs.